# Dynamic Method invocation in Struts2

Tags: struts2

Problem Statement

```
Jsp
<s:a href="newUser.action" > New User SignIn</s:a>

Struts.xml
<action name="*User"  method="{1}" class="action.NewUser">
<result name="populate">/jsp/registerUser.jsp</result>
<result name="success">/jsp/success.jsp</result>            
</action> 

Action Class has the method 
populate(){

}
```

I am wanting to use the Dynamic Method Invocation facility of STRUTS2. In general the framework substitutes the * word into the method attribute of struts.xml file.
Is there a way in which I can use a different method name. In my case the framework is attaching the method name new() to the struts.xml file but I have a method called populate() in my action class.

Comment: that is standard way Wildcard mapping will work.

Answer (score 4):

You can try to use [Preparable interface and Prepare interceptor](http://struts.apache.org/2.3.4/docs/preparable-interface.html) for this. If your Action class implements Preparable and provides one method called prepare(), it will be always called before executing any action methods.

Answer (score 0):

There is no way to call populate method on `newUser.action`. You have to call only `populateUser.action` to call populate method.